# Spring Data Elasticsearch Repository: Query for Nested Object

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, repository

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch with a repository class. Here is My Object that I want to query through:

```
public class Person{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Location location;
}

public class Location{
    String name;
}

@Query("{\"bool\" : {"
            + "\"should\" : [ "
                + "{"
                    + "\"term\" : {"
                        + "\"firstName\" : \"?0\""
                    + "}"
                + "},"
                + "{"
                    + "\"term\" : {"
                        + "\"lastName\" : \"?0\""
                    + "}"
                + "},"
                + "{"
                    + "\"term\" : {"
                        + "\"location.name\" : \"?0\""
                    + "}"
                + "}"
            + "]"
     + "}}")
List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastName(String term);
```

I can not search in location.name - how can I change the Query that this will work?

**UPDATE Mapping**

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "firstNameNGram"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "firstNameNGram"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "firstNameNGram"
                },
                "company": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "firstNameNGram"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How looks your mapping if location object is nested you must use nested query :

[nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

query looks like:

```
"nested" : {
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        {
          "term" : {
            "location.name" : {
              "value" : "?0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "path" : "location"
}
```

Comment: Updated my Questionsection with added Mapping